# Fill a cube with small cubes with different integer side lengths

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, tessellations

We are given two (potentially unlimited) sets of cubes, say red cubes (with side $n$) and white cubes (with side $m$), with $m,n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}, m \neq n$ (let's assume $n>m$).

Using the *same* number of red and white cubes, "build" a bigger cube, in the sense that this bigger cube is tessellated with the small cubes.

What is the minimum length $\mathfrak{L}_{n,m}$ of the side of the big cube (as a function of $m$ and $n$)? (How many small cubes are used?)

As noted by @achillehui, we have

$$ \mathfrak{L}_{an,am} = a \mathfrak{L}_{n,m}, \quad a \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\},$$

so it suffices to consider the case $\text{gcd}(n,m)=1.$

- $\mathfrak{L}_{n,m}^1 = \text{lcm}(l,\frac{L}{l^2}(m^3 + n^3))$ is a solution (check my answer below for the details)
- $\mathfrak{L}_{n,m}^2 = n (m^3 + n^3)$ is a solution (due to @Logophobic)
- $\mathfrak{L}_{n,m}^3 = m (m^3 + n^3)$ and $\mathfrak{L}_{n,m}^4 = 2m (m^3 + n^3)$ are solutions for some pairs $(n,m)$.

None of them is minimal, since we have

$$ \mathfrak{L}_{4,2}^1 = 36, \quad \mathfrak{L}_{4,2}^2 = 288 $$

while $\mathfrak{L}_{4,2} = 12$ is also a solution.

Comment: Any beginnining you have in your mind

Comment: Please do it for $(2,3)$ and see whether those cuboids really form cubes

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Check my answer, I wrote all the details and the case $(3,2)$

Answer (score 5):

I write here what I have in mind; this shows that there exists a solution for all pairs $(n,m)$.

- **Step 0:** Let

$$ l = \text{lcm}(m,n) \\ L= \text{lcm} \left( \frac{l^2}{m^2},\frac{l^2}{n^2} \right)    \\ \mathfrak{L} = \text{lcm} \left(l, \frac{L}{l^2} (m^3 + n^3) \right)   $$

- **Step 1:** Let us denote by $C_1$ a square cuboid of size $l \times l \times n$, made of $(l/n)^2$ red cubes.
- **Step 2:** Let us denote by $C_2$ a square cuboid of size $l \times l \times m$, made of $(l/m)^2$ white cubes.
- **Step 3:** Square cuboid $C_3$ is made by stacking up some $C_1$'s so that it contains L red cubes. In order to do this, we stack up $ \frac{L}{\frac{l^2}{n^2}} = \frac{L n^2}{l^2}$ cuboids $C_1$; since the heigth of $C_1$ is $n$, $C_3$ has dimensions

$$ l \times l \times \frac{L n^3}{l^2} $$

- **Step 4:** Analogously to Step 3, square cuboid $C_4$ is obtained by stacking up $\frac{L m^2}{l^2}$ cuboids $C_2$, contains $L$ white cubes and has dimensions

$$ l \times l \times \frac{L m^3}{l^2} $$

- **Step 5:** now we stack up one cuboid $C_3$ and one cuboid $C_4$ and this gives cuboid $C_5$; $C_5$ contains $2 L$ cubes ($L$ red and $L$ white) and has dimensions

$$ l \times l \times \left( \frac{L n^3}{l^2} + \frac{L m^3}{l^2} \right) = l \times l \times \frac{L }{l^2} (m^3 + n^3)$$

- **Step 6:** Using $$\frac{\mathfrak{L}}{l} \cdot \frac{\mathfrak{L}}{l} \cdot \frac{\mathfrak{L}}{\frac{L }{l^2} (m^3 + n^3)} $$ cuboids $C_5$, we can build the big cube, with dimensions $\mathfrak{L} \times \mathfrak{L} \times \mathfrak{L}$. This cube contains $$ \frac{\mathfrak{L}}{l} \cdot \frac{\mathfrak{L}}{l} \cdot \frac{\mathfrak{L}}{\frac{L }{l^2} (m^3 + n^3)} \cdot 2L = \frac{2 \mathfrak{L}^3}{m^3 + n^3} $$ small cubes (half red and half white).

---

**Case $(n,m)=(3,2)$**

Here is what we get when $n=3$ and $m=2$ are put into the solution.

- We have $l=6, L=36, \mathfrak{L}=210$.
- Cuboid 3: $6 \times 6 \times 27$, made of 36 red cubes.
- Cuboid 4: $6 \times 6 \times 8$, made of 36 white cubes.
- Cuboid 5: $6 \times 6 \times 35$, made of 36 red cubes and 36 white cubes (cuboid 3 + cuboid 4)
- Cube: $210 \times 210 \times 210$, using $7350 (=35 \cdot 35 \cdot 6)$ cuboids 5; there are $264600 (=7350 \cdot 36)$ white cubes and $264600$ red cubes.

---

**Case $\text{GCD}(m,n)=1$**

If $m$ and $n$ are coprime, then the expression can be simplified

$$ l = mn, \quad L= m^2 n^2, \quad \mathfrak{L}=m n (m^3 + n^3) $$

$ 2 m^3 n^3 (m^3 + n^3)^2$ cubes are used ($m^3 n^3 (m^3 + n^3)^2$ for each color).

---

**Case $n=a m$**

$$ l = n, \quad L= a^2, \quad \mathfrak{L}= n (1 + a^3) $$

$ 2 n^3 \left(1 + \left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^3\right)^2$ cubes are used ($n^3 \left(1 + \left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^3\right)^2$ for each color).

Comment: One thing I notice is you can assume $\gcd(m,n) = 1$. This is because the vertices of the small cubes are constrained on a cubic lattice of lattice spacing $ \gcd(m,n)$ (the distance of any face of any small cube to the face of the large cube is a linear combination of $m$ and $n$ and hence is a multiple of $\gcd(m,n)$). Allowing $\gcd(m,n) > 1$ won't give you any new configuration.

Comment: @achillehui Are you suggesting that there has to be an "easy" relation between $\mathfrak{L}_{dn,dm}$ and $\mathfrak{L}_{n,m}$, with $\text{gcd}(n,m)=1$? If so, what relation?

Comment: $\mathfrak{L}_{dn,dm} = d\mathfrak{L}_{n,m}$.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is not minimal. I will provide a few examples.

I previously suggested that $\mathfrak{L} = m(m^3+n^3)$ is always a solution. That assumption proved false. However, $\mathfrak{L} = n(m^3+n^3)$ is a solution, though not always minimal.

**Case** $(n,m)=(3,2) : \mathfrak{L} = m(m^3+n^3) = 70$

- Cube $70 \times 70 \times 70$ can be filled with $(m^3+n^3)^3=42,875$ cubes $m$
- Replace $n^3(m^3+n^3)^2=33,075$ cubes $m$ with $m^3(m^3+n^3)^2=9,800$ cubes $n$
- Cube $70 \times 70 \times 70$ then contains $9,800$ each of cubes $m$ and $n$

**Case** $(n,m)=(5,2) : \mathfrak{L} = n(m^3+n^3) = 665$

- Cube $665 \times 665 \times 665$ can be filled with $(m^3+n^3)^3=2,352,637$ cubes $n$
- Replace $m^3(m^3+n^3)^2=141,512$ cubes $n$ with $n^3(m^3+n^3)^2=2,211,125$ cubes $m$
- Cube $665 \times 665 \times 665$ then contains $2,211,125$ each of cubes $m$ and $n$

**Case** $(n,m)=(4,2) : \mathfrak{L} = 12$

- Cube $12 \times 12 \times 12$ can be filled with $27$ cubes $n$
- Replace $3$ cubes $n$ with $24$ cubes $m$
- Cube $12 \times 12 \times 12$ then contains $24$ each of cubes $m$ and $n$

I have revised my solution for $\mathfrak{L}_{n,m}=km$ to be stated more clearly. I have also taken into account achille hue's observation that $\mathfrak{L}_{dn,dm} = d\mathfrak{L}_{n,m}$ so this solution assumes $\text{gcd}(n,m)=1$
$$\mathfrak{L}_{dn,dm} = d\mathfrak{L}_{n,m}=kdm\\ \text{where $k$ is the least positive integer satisfying}\\(m^3+n^3)|k^3 \text{ and } \left\lfloor\frac{k}{n}\right\rfloor^3 \ge \frac{k^3}{(m^3+n^3)}$$
Unfortunately, this still does not guarantee a minimal solution because we could also find
$$\mathfrak{L}_{dn,dm} = d\mathfrak{L}_{n,m}=kdn\\ \text{where $k$ is the least positive integer satisfying}\\(m^3+n^3)|k^3 \text{ and } \left\lfloor\frac{k}{m}\right\rfloor^3 \ge \frac{k^3}{(m^3+n^3)}$$
Which will in some cases provide a more minimal solution. Case in point: $$\mathfrak{L}_{5,3}=38n=190 \lt \mathfrak{L}_{5,3}=76m=228$$
Proof that such cubes can be constructed:

- Cube with edge length $kdm$ will have $\frac{(km)^3}{(m^3+n^3)}$ of each cube size.
- This is an integer because $(m^3+n^3)|k^3$
- The cube can be filled with $k^3$ cubes $dm$
- $n^3$ cubes $dm$ in sub-cube with edge length $dnm$ can be replaced with $m^3$ cubes $dn$
- This replacement must be repeated $\frac{k^3}{(m^3+n^3)}$ times so that the cube contains $\frac{(km)^3}{(m^3+n^3)}$ cubes $dn$
- The replacement can be completed because $\left\lfloor\frac{k}{n}\right\rfloor^3 \ge \frac{k^3}{(m^3+n^3)}$

Using $\mathfrak{L}_{3,2}=35m$ as an example (this is the same as Case $(n,m) = (3,2)$ above.)

- Cube with edge length $70$ will have $\frac{70^3}{35} = 9800$ of each cube
- The cube can be filled with $35^3 = 42,875$ cubes $m$
- $27$ cubes $m$ in sub-cube with edge length $6$ can be replaced with $8$ cubes $n$
- This replacement must be repeated $\frac{35^3}{35} = 1225$ times so that the cube contains $9800$ cubes $n$
- The replacement can be completed because $\left\lfloor\frac{35}{3}\right\rfloor^3 = 11^3 = 1331 \gt 1225$

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how we can find that $12$ from $2$ and $4$? ($4^3 + 2^3 = 72 = 6 \cdot 12$, what does that $6$ mean?)

Comment: I was pondering that yesterday: your solution for $n=am$ was $\mathfrak{L}= n (1 + a^3)$. Instead, we find $k^3=x(1+a^3)$ then $\mathfrak{L}= kn$. Since $1+2^3=3^2$, we find $k^3=3^3$ so that $\mathfrak{L}= 3n = 12$. Also, for case $(n,m)=(5,2)$ I see a better solution: $\mathfrak{L} = 2m(m^3+n^3) = 532$

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a complete minimal solution

Comment: @PaoloFranchi My solution has been updated again.

Comment: Can you prove your assertions by actually building a cube with those sides?

Comment: @PaoloFranchi Proof added. Let me know if you need further clarification.